# tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath cannot detect any click

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I create a `UITableView` and connect it to datasource and delegate in storyboard and put `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` on class. And of course `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to make push to another `UIViewcontroller`.

I called

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

on `viewDidLoad`.

This is my `didSelectRowAtIndexpPath:` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseContentFreeIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FreeTableViewCell
    print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath eshops")
    let row = indexPath.row
    print("business row:\(HCPartner[row])")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "eshopsURL", sender: self)
}
```

When I clicked a cell row, it does not detect any click and it does not show any log of `print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath eshops")`.

Why does `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` not work? I tried it on swift 2, it works. But in swift 3 it did not work.

What is wrong with my code? What is the correct code to make it detect click on cell row of a `UITableView`?

My viewcell hierarchy like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post an image of your cell view hierarchy?

Comment: already update with image of cell view hierarchy

Comment: Open your cell view hierarchy to see what is inside your cell, sorry if I wasn't clear enough

Comment: update image already sent in question

Comment: Your tableView shows your data? only the selection is missing?

Comment: my tableview can show data. but cell row cannot clicked and print log of "didSelectRowAtIndexPath eshops". this log only appear when it detect click on cell row.

Comment: @Sarimin - Did you implemented `willSelectRowAt`? If yes, can you please post the sample code of that function.

Comment: @ViniApp , I did not implemented willSelectRowAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not added any Gesture and UserInteraction is Enabled.

Comment: user interaction is enable

Comment: are you using gesture in tableview?

Comment: I use standard tableview. did standard tableview in swift 3 need to add gesture? In swift 2, standard tableview work properly with delegate and datasource.

Comment: no, but you can not use gesture with tableview, if you are using then didselect will not work, another solution is use a button which frame is equal to cell. you can trigger button Like this :-            cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
                             cel.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnActionForCell(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: Wow you correct this bug. thank you @Pushpendra Mishra

Comment: @PushpendraMishra but there is no need to add any button if we have an already delegate method for that. Your answer is right but it depends upon the requirement. Main thing is that if DidSelect is not working then there must mu something with the code or any other thing is blocking the interface of UItableview.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the TableView Delegate and Datasource in the Class ->

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
}

Comment: Are your other Delegate methods like: numberOfRowsInSection, CellForRowAtIndexpath Called??

Comment: other delegate method are: func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int , func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int, func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell . this other delegate methods works normal.

Comment: Swift 3 modified the signature of the method lot of methods:

Replace:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) with 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

May Be This Helps You.

Comment: @Sarimin This won't fix your issue with `didSelectRowAt` but you have the wrong method signature for the `numberOfSections` method.

Comment: @rmaddy.. Thanks for correcting my Answer :) 

This is the correct syntax.
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 0
}

Comment: already try, if return 0 it did not show any row. but if return 1 it shown all row. but still did not work or cannot detect click on cell row.

Comment: Hey, 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int,

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell,

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int.......

All the above three methods are of UITableViewDataSource protocol. Whereas-> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  is a method of UITableViewDelegate Protocol.

So, Please ensure that your UITableViewDelegate protocol is set properly in Storyboard as well as in viewDidLoad.

Comment: update picture of delegate and datasource on storyboard. it is already there for delegate and data source for tableview.

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if your tableView is actually connected to an `IBOutlet`.  I suspect your `self.tableView` in `viewDidLoad` is actually nil.

Also, check your storyboard to make sure the actual cells have a "default" selection style.  You might have accidentally set the selection style to `.none`.

It should look something like this:
[image: Selection Style popup menu]

Comment: tableview selection -> single selection. tableviewcell selection ->default. already set like that as usual but did not work until i make a question here.

Comment: tableview already connected to class as referencing outlet as usual but did not work.